# How do I get a repeated row and add as a column in SQL?

Tags: sql

I've read many different questions here and I didn't find this one, even though it looks like something people would do sometimes.
What I have is a table looking like this:

```
Person_id   Person_Phone_Number
a           11545623
b           21323545
c           45654655
d           54455896
e           21458437
f           14564680
a           32545542
c           98745682
e           10589621
g           23568954
a           56468756
```

And what I need as the output is this:

```
Person_id   Person_Phone_Number    New_Column_1    New_Column_2
a           11545623               32545542        56468756
b           21323545
c           45654655               98745682
d           54455896
e           21458437               10589621
f           14564680
g           23568954
```

Comment: That'd be a pivot query, and the exact mechanics/syntax for doing that depends on what DB you're using.

Comment: Adding to @MarcB's comment - it's _much_ easier to do that in the display layer (report, web page, form, etc.) rather than the data layer that likes to have fixed columns.

Answer (score 0):

IF SQL Server

```
;with cteBase as (
      Select *,RowNr = Row_Number() over (Partition By Person_id Order By Person_Phone_Number)
       From  @YourTable
)
Select Person_ID
      ,Person_Phone_Number = max(case when RowNr=1 then Person_Phone_Number else '' end)     
      ,New_Column_1        = max(case when RowNr=2 then Person_Phone_Number else '' end)       
      ,New_Column_2        = max(case when RowNr=3 then Person_Phone_Number else '' end)       
 From  cteBase
 Group By Person_ID
 Order By 1
```

Returns

```
Person_ID   Person_Phone_Number    New_Column_1    New_Column_2
a           11545623               32545542        56468756
b           21323545        
c           45654655               98745682 
d           54455896        
e           10589621               21458437 
f           14564680        
g           23568954
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Your are 100% correct.   Updated.